# code::blocks linking doesn't work for lib files

Tags: compilation, linker, static-libraries, codeblocks, static-linking

I just had a fresh new version of Code::Blocks(12.11) and tried to make a glut example project, but the generated code has some linking issues.

The minGW settings are is set to the correct values, since I successfully linked ad compiled a glfw project from *.a files. My problem is the linker just can't handle .lib files for some reason. I always get undefined reference errors, despite of the linking of the correct libraries.

I just don't know what to do/link...

---

**How can I link *.lib files in the new Code::blocks?

IF I cannot, are there any glut binaries in the format of *.a files, or should I build it myself?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found [this](http://mycodelog.com/2010/05/15/gllibs/) link, used this package, and did a clean build(rebuild) of the project, instead of Build. Works like a charm!